# Finding a matrix such that $AX=I_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would I go about answering this question? I thought of multiplying both sides by   $A^{-1}$ but that will not get me a $4 \times 3$ matrix, any hints/suggestions would be appreciated.

> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 2 & -3 & 1 & 0 \\
> -1 & 5 & 2 & 3 \\
> -4 & 0 & 5 & 2 
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   Find all $4 \times 3$ matrices $X$ such that $AX=I_3$.

(original picture: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac7Vo.png))

Comment: hint: start by finding a solution to $Ax = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0 \end{bmatrix}$. Where $x$ is (4x1) and the vector on the right hand side is the first column of $\mathrm{I}^3$

Comment: You could note that the first three columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $A = \begin{bmatrix} B & u \end{bmatrix}$, and $X = \begin{bmatrix} C \\ v^T \end{bmatrix}$.

Then (by computing the determinant, or other means) notice that $B$ is invertible.

You have $BC + u v^T = I$, which gives $C = B^{-1}(I - u v ^T)$. Hence 
$X = \begin{bmatrix} B^{-1}(I - u v ^T) \\ v^T \end{bmatrix}$.

**Addendum**:
We try to solve the following system by reducing $A$ to
reduced row echelon form:
$A X = I$. If we partition $A$ and $X$ as above ($B,C$ are $3 \times 3$, $u,v$ are $ 3 \times 1$), we get
$\begin{bmatrix} B & u \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} C \\ v^T \end{bmatrix} = I$, which after row reduction looks like
$\begin{bmatrix} I & B^{-1} u \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} C \\ v^T \end{bmatrix} = B^{-1}$. Expanding the left hand side gives
$\begin{bmatrix} I & B^{-1} u \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} C \\ v^T \end{bmatrix} = C + B^{-1} u v^T$, hence we have $C + B^{-1} u v^T = B^{-1}$ from which we get
$C = B^{-1} - B^{-1} u v^T$.

The point is that **all** solutions have this form, and if we choose **any** $v$, we can compute the corresponding $C = B^{-1} - B^{-1} u v^T$. Then
$X = \begin{bmatrix} C \\ v^T \end{bmatrix}$ is a solution.

Comment: oh.. this answer incorporates methods and notation I have not studied yet. But thank you anyway

Comment: I have tried to elaborate a little, but I'm not sure what bothers you...